# c# app doesn't work in win7 home premium

Tags: c#, windows

I have build a c# application in my windows 7 ultimate laptop and I moved it to another laptop with windows 7 home premium, both 64bit version. In the second laptop I get an error message that says :

> error MSB8007: The Platform for project 'project_name' is invalid.
>   Platform='MCB'. You may be seeing this message because you are trying
>   to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a
>   non-default Platform that doesn't exist for this project.
>   [project_path].

In my app I create a process of MSBuild.. I tried to test all of .NET Framework version I have in laptop (2.0 - 4). I get this error in v4, in older version I get another error (because sth is not working with oldest versions with VS 2010). Can anyone provide me a solution? Is there a solution?

Comment: What type of visual studio application type, winform, wpf mvc? 64bit app or not..

Comment: It is a Windows Form Application. I 'm not sure if it is 64bit or not...I 'm new in VS. Where can I see this?

Answer (score 0):

Olga, 
Try this.

On the laptop where you originally created the project,

1. Take a back up copy of your entire project by copying it to another folder or creating a ZIP file.
2. Open Visual Studio (the same one you used to create the project) and open the project.
3. Now from the menu, open Build > Configuration Manager.
4. On the box that appears, you will have two drop downs on the top. The one on your right hand side will be titled "Active Solution platform". Open this drop down, do you see anything called MCB ? If yes, click the "" option. Another box will popup.
5. If you also see an option called "Any CPU", click on "MCB" and click the "Remove" button. If there is no "Any CPU", then click the "Rename" button and rename MCB -> "Any CPU".
6. Back in the Build Configuration Manager screen (what you opened in Step 2), set that same drop down to "Any CPU".
7. Test that your project builds by firing a build and then running your app.
8. Transfer your entire project back to the new laptop.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I only see "x86" in Active Solution Platform drop down..Nothing else, only <New> and <Edit>..Do you have any other suggestion??

Comment: Ok, tell me what are the options you see on the new computer?